# Do you have to live in the US to sign up for the beta of Hearthstone: Heroes of WarCraft?

Tags: hearthstone

I've read over the [Hearthstone FAQs](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/faq/#q6a), but unless I missed something didn't see an answer. Just that I could opt in for the [Hearthstone beta via my Battle.net](https://battle.net/account/management/beta-profile.html?hearthstone) account.

Are gamers interested in the beta test of Hearthstone: Heroes of WarCraft required to live in the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Battle.net account is set to European and I could apply for the beta, so at least Europe is covered as well.

I just read through the [Hearthstone FAQ](http://battle.net/hearthstone/faq/) and it states the following:

> I don’t live in the US; can I still participate in the beta test?
>
> We hope to launch a beta test in other game regions after the initial beta-test
> launch in North America, but we don’t have any specifics to announce at this time.
> Stay tuned for updates.

This means that for now, only US residents can play the beta, but other regions will follow after the initial beta-test launch.

**UPDATE** 08/10/2013: The Hearthstone Closed beta is now available to selected European Players as well.

Comment: Kevin not sure how I missed that, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Kevin: Why did you reject @ahsteele's edit? To me, it seemed pretty good. In my opinion, the reason you picked ("This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.") doesn't fit the edit, since he improved the grammar and formatting, added the link, and removed the "Edit" text which we prefer not to appear in answers.

Comment: @schism Because he added grammar errors as well.

Comment: Gotcha; I reread it and there was that one error (easily rectified by changing indicated to present tense) but I noticed he also changed some of the wording, which I guess you may not have been delighted about; I've edited your post to fix the formatting of the quotation. Incidentally, you can click the "Edit" button if you feel like some of the suggested edit is of value so as to still give him partial credit for the edit.